# Interpreting Results of Time Series Decomposition

Tags: time-series, seasonality, trend

Suppose, after ACF and PCF investigation, I see my data has strong seasonality. I do both additive and multiplicative time series decomposition, just to check it results.

I am not interested in forecasting, but want to investigate seasonal nature of variable. My question is how does one interpret this result. For example, can I say January has 20% more 'x' as compared to what?

[[Multiplicative Decomposition]
[]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAeo7.png)

[[additive Decomposition][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKkzQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKkzQ.png)

Comment: Your two plots are identical. (And I assume the second one should be called "*additive*", not "addictive".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"can I say January has 20% more 'x' as compared to what?" - compared to the time point where the seasonal decomposition indicates a zero effect, which seems to happen in early June. [*Ceteris paribus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus) of course, i.e., assuming the other components held constant.

There is really not all that much more to interpret in a time series decomposition.